# Observer Design pattern - Getting a segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, observer-pattern

I am writing an Observer design pattern where `Subject` knows what `Observer` it has (same as the original design) *and* `Observer` also knows what `Subject` it's attached to, mainly to tackle scenarios like `Observer` going out of scope and `Subject` has a reference to a destroyed object.

So if an `Observer` watches a `Subject`, both know about each other. This is handled via `observer->removeSubject` and `observer->addSubject`.

In the following snippet, I am testing a case where `Observer`s go out of scope, meaning `~Observer()` gets invoked first however I seem to be getting a segfault on the following line when I debug [in an online gdb tool](https://onlinegdb.com/N4lWmoeW4) in the second iteration of `~Observer()`

```
std::cout << "Observers size = " << _observers.size() << "\n";
```

```
template<typename T>
class Subject;

template<typename T>
class Observer
{
    std::set<Subject<T>*> _subjects;

    public:
    virtual void update(T val) = 0;

    void addSubject(Subject<T>* subject)
    {
        printf ("[Observer] Adding Subject to observer - ");
        _subjects.insert(subject);
        std::cout << "Subject size = " << _subjects.size() << "\n\n";
    }

    void removeSubject(Subject<T>* subject)
    {
        printf ("[Observer] Removing Subject from observer - ");
        _subjects.erase(subject);
        std::cout << "Subject size = " << _subjects.size() << "\n";
    }

    virtual ~Observer()
    {
        printf ("\n~Observer\nSubject Size = %ld\n", _subjects.size());
        for (auto& subject : _subjects)
        {
            subject->detach(this); 
        }
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Subject
{
    std::set<Observer<T>*> _observers;

    protected:
    Subject() = default;

    public:
    void attach(Observer<T>* observer)
    {
        printf ("~~ [Subject] Attaching observer ~~\n");
        _observers.insert(observer);
        observer->addSubject(this);
    }
    
    void detach(Observer<T>* observer)
    {
        printf ("~~ [Subject] Detaching observer ~~\n");
        std::cout << "Observers size = " << _observers.size() << "\n";
        _observers.erase(observer);
        observer->removeSubject(this);
    }

    void notify(const T& val)
    {
        for (auto& observer : _observers)
        {
            observer->update(val);
        }
    }
    
    virtual ~Subject()
    {
        printf ("\n~Subject\n");
        printf ("Observer size = %ld\n", _observers.size());
        for (auto& obs : _observers)
        {
            obs->removeSubject(this); 
        }
    }
};

template<typename T>
class ConcreteSubject : public Subject<T>
{
    T _value;

    public:
    void set(const T& value)
    {
        _value = value;
        this->notify(value);
    }
};

template<typename T>
class ConcreteObserver : public Observer<T>
{
    public:
    void update(T value)
    {
        std::cout << "Observer Notified: " << value << "\n";
    }
};

int main() 
{
    ConcreteSubject<int> sub;
    {
        ConcreteObserver<int> obs;
        ConcreteObserver<int> obs1;
        sub.attach(&obs);
        sub.attach(&obs1);
        sub.set(5);
    }   
}
```

One part that I am concerned about is the following where `subject` is removed from `_subjects` while `_subjects` is being iterated over.
Should a copy of `_subjects` be made to be iterated over in `~Observer()` instead?

```
    void removeSubject(Subject<T>* subject)
    {
        printf ("[Observer] Removing Subject from observer - ");
        _subjects.erase(subject);
        std::cout << "Subject size = " << _subjects.size() << "\n";
    }

    virtual ~Observer()
    {
        printf ("\n~Observer\nSubject Size = %ld\n", _subjects.size());
        for (auto& subject : _subjects)
        {
            subject->detach(this); 
        }
     }
```

Comment: OT: please note that mixing `printf` and `std::cout` isn't usually a good idea.

Comment: Yes, as I have been writing my answer, you updated the questions and you pointed exactly the same problem and the same solution as I did... Yes, making a copy of `_subjects` can solve this very easily.

Comment: I didn't care much while writing a sample code but I do agree with that. Thanks

Comment: @Bob__ Why? C and C++ output streams are implicitly tied together at the start of the program to prevent issues when mixing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more problems in your code but I can see at last this one:

When `Observer` is being destroyed in destructor, it iterates over `_subjects` collection. You call `Subject::detach()` on each subject. `Subject::detach()` in turn calls `Observer::removeSubject()` on the very same observer and `Observer::removeSubject()` removes the subject from the very same `_subjects` collection which you are currently iterating upon. This is undefined behaviour which later probably leads to the segfault you are having.

**Solution 1**

In `Observer::~Observer()` you can make a copy of the `_subjects` collection and iterate on this copy. This seems to be the simplest solution.

**Solution 2**

```
virtual ~Observer()
{
  while (!_subjects.empty())
  {
    (*_subjects.begin())->detach(this); 
  }
}
```

**Solution 3**

This solution may actually be the most performant one.
If you are destroying the `Observer` you do not need to clear the `_subjects` collection one by one because the observer object will be destroyed anyway. Therefore you may introduce a private `bool _destroying` member variable. Its default value will be `false` but in the destructor it would be set to `true`. And when true, it would prevent removing from `_subjects` collection in `removeSubject()`.

```
void removeSubject(Subject<T>* subject)
{
  if (!_destroying)
  {
    _subjects.erase(subject);
  }
}

virtual ~Observer()
{
  _destroying = true;
  for (auto& subject : _subjects)
  {
    subject->detach(this); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to be more precise, is iterating over something that's being modified i.e appended/removed elsewhere UB? In this case being `_subjects` collection

Comment: Yes. In this case it is. There are other ways of iterating which are safe. I have updated the answer with alterative solution which should be fine without making a copy.

Comment: iterating over `std::set` isn't going to be sequential, is it? If it isn't, it makes sense that a segfault happens but if it's sequential (just like you have in your alternative code), it should work. Right? Which other solution you got in mind? Appreciate the effort

Comment: @xyf Not sure what you mean by sequential here? Range-based loop is a syntax sugar over plain old `for` loop using iterators. It will do `iter++;` by the end of the iteration, but `iter` is already invalidated by `erase()` call.

Comment: how is your alternative solution different from the range-based loop then? I see you're explicitly using `begin()` on the iterator which is to get the first object in the set

Comment: In solution 2, I am taking a new `begin()` iterator in each cycle. Therefore it never gets invalidated by `erase()` call. The cycle ends when the collection is empty.

Comment: I have added also solution 3. It relies on the fact that in the destructor you do not need to care about clearing of the `_subjects` collection so you can skip it.